# Positioning of live chat window on webpage

Tags: usability, chat

Where is the best place for a live chat window on a webpage, so it doesn’t hinder the user’s navigation?

Comment: The question seems to suggest what the answer should be... somewhere away from the navigation elements of the webpage. You could also look at a movable/dockable window so users can place it where they like.

Comment: To help provide better answers, perhaps provide a mockup of the webpage layout?

Comment: Placing it on the opposite side to the navigation with an option to move and dock as Michael suggested is probably the best option.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on where your user navigation is located on the page already.

Maybe take a Facebook chat approach in the bottom right corner.

It's consistent placement with what's already out there, and it's not obtrusive since how likely is a vital component already in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Yes, google chat also does this. Also it is a similar area to where toast alerts pop up, so users already know that boxes can "pop up" in this area of the screen.

Comment: Completely forgot about Google chat, and I was unaware of the term "toast alert" so thanks!